# unable to use notifications with tablayout (material theme crash)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/albumTabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:tabBackground="@color/main_light_grey"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/list_blue"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/albumTabPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/main_light_grey"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

However I am trying to add notification and I am using the following code

```
tab.getOrCreateBadge().setNumber(2);
```

but I get the error saying that I need to make sure this component is using Material theme or decident.
The component is com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout  (my app is not) .What can I do?

if I do this

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout"
```

Then it crashes complaining about inflator. This is in a fragment
What do you suggest I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use **BadgeDrawable**?

```
BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = tabLayout.getTabAt(4).getOrCreateBadge();
badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);
badgeDrawable.setNumber(5);
```

Comment: Follow this link [https://material.io/develop/android/components/tab-layout/](https://material.io/develop/android/components/tab-layout/)

Comment: Yes I did. and this is why the crash is happening

Comment: Also i can't find where you used it in your posted code

Comment: Make sure your ```AppTheme``` is inheriting from ```Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar```